# phpExcel заполнение прайса на Simpla CMS

Tags: php, phpexcel

Не получается правильно записать данные в прайс.
Имеется Категория-->подкатегория-->товары.(правильная последовательность)
Код:

```
$oSheet = $oPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        foreach($aCategories as $iCatId => $oCategory) {
if( isset($oCategory->subcategories) ||  isset($aProductCategories[$iCatId])) {
            $oSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $this->iRowCount, str_repeat('         ', count($oCategory->path) - 1) . $oCategory->name);

                $style = array(

                    'font' => array(

                        'bold' => true,

                        'size'  => 11

                    )

                );

                $oSheet->mergeCells('A' . $this->iRowCount . ':D' . $this->iRowCount . '');

                $oSheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow(0, $this->iRowCount)->applyFromArray($style);

                $this->iRowCount++;


                if(isset($aProductCategories[$iCatId])) {

                    foreach($aProductCategories[$iCatId] as $oProduct) {...
```

Далее идет заполнение товара...
Если нужно предоставлю весь код.
А выводит он следующее (для наглядности [скрин](http://prntscr.com/bn1olq))

```
    Категория
    Категория
    Категория
    Категория
    Категория
    Категория
Подкатегория
товар
товар
товар
Подкатегория
товар
товар
товар
и тд..
```

Как не химичил к такому виду (Категория-->подкатегория-->товары.) не привел.
Но удалось вывести категория-->подкатегория
 Но товары все равно [Ушел вниз](http://prntscr.com/bn1p6u) 
Как вывести правильно, мозги кипят...